# How to go to New Record with all clear form controls

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with its controls bound to `tbl1`.
I used to use `DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec` without problems but since
I added a listbox with `2` bound columns to the subform, my button `btnNewRec` sub has stopped working as expected. My aim is to open the subform in a New Record entry mode where the controls are all empty. I have:

subform's `btnNewRec`Button:

```
Private btnNewRec_Click()
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
Me.txtNo.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Subform Current event:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
If Me.NewRecord Then
Me.txtNo.SetFocus
End If
With Me.listBox
Me!listBox = Me.txtNo.Value
End With
End Sub
```

Subform Load event:

```
Private Sub Form_Load
With Me.listBox
.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM tbl1"
listBox.Selected(1) = True
Me.listBox.SetFocus
End With
```

The ListBox's AfterUpdate event:

```
Private Sub listBox_AfterUpdate()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
If Not IsNull(txtNo) And Not IsNull(txtName) Then
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
rs.FindFirst ("[txtNo] = '" & Me![listBox] & "'")
If Not rs.NoMatch Then
    Me.Dirty = False
    Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    Else
    Exit Sub
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End If
If IsNull(txtNo) Or IsNull(txtName) Then
Exit Sub
End If
```

Thank you!

Comment: Found out that my form controls has default values on them. I didn't set them and I don't know how it all happened.

Comment: Usually table columns add default values upon creation but can be set at control level as well in the properties tab. To clear, open the table in design mode and delete the default value for the column.